# Google Calendar API is receiving invalid_grant

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using Google API's to read a calendar.  I haven't used it in a few months, and find that I'm receiving an error when I run my PHP script "quickstart.php".  Here's the error message:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs>php quickstart.php

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
} in C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(181): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#3 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(779): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array)
#4 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(232): Google_Client->execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#5 C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Google\Servic in C:\php\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

C:\Apache24\htdocs>
```

How do I go about addressing this problem?

QUICKSTART.PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
// [START calendar_quickstart]
//require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//$first_date = "2018-09-25 01:00:00"; //First date to extract from calendar
$first_date = "2023-06-14 01:00:00"; //First date to extract from calendar
$file_name = "C:\\Users\\Phil\\Documents\\Saint Susanna\Refugee\\calendar.txt";
require 'C:\php\vendor\autoload.php';
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setRedirectUri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
//  REMOVED ON 11/26/2018 PER BUG RESOLUTION FROM GOOGLE DOCS
//  $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['localhost'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';

    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {

        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
//Open the text file in write mode and truncate the data as long as no other process has it open.
$handle = fopen($file_name, "w"); 
//Write out the header row
$heading_array = array("Start Time", "End Time", "Event Summary", "Location", "Created Date", "Updated Date", "Description");
fputcsv($handle, $heading_array, "|");

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
//$calendarId = 'primary';  REMOVED ON 11/26/2018 TO UTILIZE THE ALTERNATE CALENDAR "WELCOMING A REFUGEE FAMILY"
$calendarId = 'vtq6tdk468in2dtitql2fqeg60@group.calendar.google.com';
//Construct $first_day in ISO8601 format for the query parameter
$first_day = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($first_date)); 
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 1000,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => $first_day,
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        $created = $event->getCreated();
        $updated = $event->getUpdated();
        $summary = $event->getSummary();
        $description = $event->getDescription();
        $location = $event->getLocation();
        $end = $event->end->dateTime;
        //Reformat date fields from ISO8601 into the EST time zone, and then into a different format.
        $start = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $start, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
        $start = $start->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
        $end =     DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $end, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
        $end =         $end->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
//      The Created and Updated dates aren't true ISO8601.  It was easier to subtract 5 hours from GMT
        $created = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime('-5 hours', strtotime($created)));
        $updated = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime('-5 hours', strtotime($updated)));
//      Load the array with the event's fields
        $event_array = array($start, $end, $summary, $location, $created, $updated, $description);
//      printf("\n Created=  $created \n Updated= $updated \n Summary= $summary \n Description= $description \n Location= $location \n Start= $end \n End= $end \n");
//      var_dump($event_array);
//      Write the array to the file.
        fputcsv($handle, $event_array, "|");
        }
}
// Close the txt file
fclose($handle);
print ("The file $file_name should be written and closed");
// [END calendar_quickstart]
```

I hesitated to post such a big file.  I'm not sure where the code fails, so I didn't know what would constitute a snipet in this case.
Thanks for looking at this.

This is the first part of REST.PHP:

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

use Google\Auth\HttpHandler\HttpHandlerFactory;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

/**
 * This class implements the RESTful transport of apiServiceRequest()'s
 */
class Google_Http_REST
{
  /**
   * Executes a Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface and (if applicable) automatically retries
   * when errors occur.
   *
   * @param Google_Client $client
   * @param Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $req
   * @return array decoded result
   * @throws Google_Service_Exception on server side error (ie: not authenticated,
   *  invalid or malformed post body, invalid url)
   */
  public static function execute(
      ClientInterface $client,
      RequestInterface $request,
      $expectedClass = null,
      $config = array(),
      $retryMap = null
  ) {
    $runner = new Google_Task_Runner(
        $config,
        sprintf('%s %s', $request->getMethod(), (string) $request->getUri()),
        array(get_class(), 'doExecute'),
        array($client, $request, $expectedClass)
    );

    if (!is_null($retryMap)) {
      $runner->setRetryMap($retryMap);
    }

    return $runner->run();
  }

  /**
   * Executes a Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface
   *
   * @param Google_Client $client
   * @param Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $request
   * @return array decoded result
   * @throws Google_Service_Exception on server side error (ie: not authenticated,
   *  invalid or malformed post body, invalid url)
   */
  public static function doExecute(ClientInterface $client, RequestInterface $request, $expectedClass = null)
  {
    try {
      $httpHandler = HttpHandlerFactory::build($client);
      $response = $httpHandler($request);
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
      // if Guzzle throws an exception, catch it and handle the response
      if (!$e->hasResponse()) {
        throw $e;
      }

      $response = $e->getResponse();
      // specific checking for Guzzle 5: convert to PSR7 response
      if ($response instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Message\ResponseInterface) {
        $response = new Response(
            $response->getStatusCode(),
            $response->getHeaders() ?: [],
            $response->getBody(),
            $response->getProtocolVersion(),
            $response->getReasonPhrase()
        );
      }
    }

    return self::decodeHttpResponse($response, $request, $expectedClass);
  }

  /**
   * Decode an HTTP Response.
   * @static
   * @throws Google_Service_Exception
   * @param Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $response The http response to be decoded.
   * @param Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response
   * @return mixed|null
   */
  public static function decodeHttpResponse(
      ResponseInterface $response,
      RequestInterface $request = null,
      $expectedClass = null
  ) {
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();

    // retry strategy
    if ((intVal($code)) >= 400) {
      // if we errored out, it should be safe to grab the response body
      $body = (string) $response->getBody();

      // Check if we received errors, and add those to the Exception for convenience
      throw new Google_Service_Exception($body, $code, null, self::getResponseErrors($body));
    }
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide the code, I searched for some quickstart.php and tried to replicate it and I didn't get an error. Can you provide the code that you use?

Comment: Thank you for the code. As per checking, we have used the same code. Just to confirm, did you use External user in APIs & Services \> OAuth consent screen \> User type and publishing status is set to testing. If yes, have you generated a fresh token? You can check this link as [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Comment: Hello Serenity.  I ended up deleting the TOKEN.JSON file and it was regenerated.  Thanks for the help.